# There is a function which is continuous but not differentiable

Tags: derivatives

I have a function which is a convergent series:

$$f(x) = \sin(x) + \frac{1}{10}\sin(10x) + \frac{1}{100}\sin(100x) + \cdots \frac{1}{10^n}\sin(10^nx)$$

This function is convergent because for any E you care to specify, the function has a term which is smaller than E.  However, the function is not differentiable, and I don't understand why.

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \cos(x)+\frac{10}{10}\cos(10x) + \frac{100}{100}\cos(100x) + \cdots \frac{10^n}{10^n}\cos(10^nx)$$

Is this a special case to [A Continuous Nowhere-Differentiable Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258442/a-continuous-nowhere-differentiable-function) ?

Comment: Are you still waiting on an answer? If not, would you accept one of the current answers?

Answer (score 2):

First note that $\sum a_k$ is **absolutely convergent** if 
$$\sum \left|a_k\right|\Rightarrow  \mbox{converges}$$
Since absolute convergence implies convergence, then let's check for absolute convergence 
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left|\frac{\sin\left(10^kx\right)}{10^k}\right|$$
First note that
$$ \left|\sin\left(10^kx\right)\right|\leq 1 $$
$$ \frac{\left|\sin\left(10^kx\right)\right|}{\left|10^k\right|} \leq \frac{1}{\left|10^k\right|} $$
$$ \left|\frac{\sin\left(10^kx\right)}{10^k}\right| \leq \left|\frac{1}{10}\right|^k $$
Since $\left|\frac{1}{10}\right|\lt 1$, then by the geometric series test,
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left|\frac{1}{10}\right|^k \Rightarrow \mbox{converges} $$
Which implies that
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^k \Rightarrow \mbox{converges absolutely} $$
Therefore by the direct comparison test, we have
$$ f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{\sin\left(10^kx\right)}{10^k} \Rightarrow \mbox{converges absolutely}$$
Now let's talk about the differentiability of $f(x)$. If we take the derivative of each term in the sum, we'll end up with
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \cos\left(10^kx\right) $$
Now let's show that this series diverges. Note that 
$$ -1\leq \cos\left(10^nx\right) $$
Since 
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} 1=1\not=0 $$
Then by the divergence test
$$ -\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 1\Rightarrow \mbox{diverges} $$
Therefore by the direct comparison test
$$ \sum\limits_{k=0}^n \cos\left(10^kx\right) \Rightarrow \mbox{diverges}$$
So although each term of $f(x)$ is differentiable and the sum of each term is convergent, **the sum of the derivative of each term does not converge**. This fact makes $f(x)$ a non differentiable function.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you plug $x=k\pi$, where $k$ is any integer, into the derivative of the that function, you get $\infty$, thereby making the derivative discontinuous. This, in other words, means that the function is not differentiable.

Comment: These answers are correct, but they do not answer my question.  Why is my function not differentiable when it is convergent and piecewise continuous?  Is there another test that a function has to have in order to be differentiable, or do I have see if the derivative exists before I can say that the function is differentiable.  In other words, it isn't sufficient that if a function is continuous, then it is differentiable.

Comment: @user1928764, continuity **does not** imply differentiability. A differentiable function is a function that is differentiable at any point in its domain.

Comment: To add to @k170 comment, consider abs(x). Certainly is continuous, but not differentiable (at all points).

Comment: @user1928764 The first question you asked in that comment is like asking, "How can't a person walk even though they have legs?" Clearly if the person is dead or paralyzed waist down they can't walk. In the same way that a person having legs doesn't necessarily mean they can walk,a function being piece-wise continuous and convergent doesn't necessarily mean that it is differentiable, despite how tempting it is to assume so.